# Android Studio Code Formatting multiple files

Tags: java, android, file, format

I already know how to format Android Studio files manually, but are there any methods that could format the code if I close a tab for example. I created a macro which formats the code on saving, but only does it on the currently viewed .java/.xml, I'm in the need of doing this all for the opened/modified files (Git) or all the project files.

The explanation: There are some screnarios, when we have to overwrite strings.xml manually outside of Android Studio, and it can mess up the formattings, so the next person always have to open the xml and hit save on it.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Answer (score 7):

If you select a package or directory in the project view on the left side you can format multiple files at once. Just select the scope (e.g. the project directory) press `Ctrl + Alt + L`.

See also the [IntelliJ documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/reformatting-source-code.html).

Comment: This answer is precise and question must have been considered solved already.